# What is the parameter in an evenetListener function?

Tags: javascript, dom, parameters, func

What is the parameter in an eventListener function?
What is the parameter (e) doing in addItem?

```js
let form = document.getElementById("addForm")
form.addEventListener("submit", addItem);

// Add item
function addItem(e) {

  e.preventDefault()
  console.log(e)

  // Get input value

  let newItem = document.getElementById("item").value

  // Create new li
  let newLI = document.createElement("li")
  // Add class

  newLI.className = "list-group-item"

  // Add text node with input

  newLI.textContent = newItem

  //Delete button

  let button = document.createElement("button")
  button.className = "btn btn-danger btn-sm float-right delete"
  button.textContent = "X"
  newLI.appendChild(button)

  itemList.appendChild(newLI)
  document.getElementById("item").value = ""
}
```

Comment: [`EventTarget.addEventListener()` -> The event listener callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#the_event_listener_callback): _"The callback function itself has the same parameters and return value as the handleEvent() method; that is, **the callback accepts a single parameter: an object based on `Event` describing the event that has occurred**, and it returns nothing."_

Comment: I made a snippet using the `[<>]` snippet editor. It is missing relevant HTML

Answer (score 2):

See [any documentation for `addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

> The callback function itself has the same parameters and return value as the handleEvent() method; that is, the callback accepts a single parameter: an object based on Event describing the event that has occurred, and it returns nothing.

and for [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event):

> The Event interface represents an event which takes place in the DOM.
>
> An event can be triggered by the user action e.g. clicking the mouse
> button or tapping keyboard, or generated by APIs to represent the
> progress of an asynchronous task. It can also be triggered
> programmatically, such as by calling the HTMLElement.click() method of
> an element, or by defining the event, then sending it to a specified
> target using EventTarget.dispatchEvent().
>
> There are many types of events, some of which use other interfaces
> based on the main Event interface. Event itself contains the
> properties and methods which are common to all events.